# Retrieve width of embedded video using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple page with an embedded video. Below is an example. I want to retrieve the width of the embedded video's iframe, which can vary ( for example if the video is from youtube or vimeo ). Then I can put a div next to it, with some text, and adjust the width of the latter accordingly

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
      <body onLoad = "resizeElements()">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a34QTcpnKww"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>  
  </body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function resizeElements() 
    {
      var iframeVideos = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
      for ( var i = 0; i < iframeVideos.length; i++) 
      {
        video = iframeVideos[i];
        alert ( ">" + video.style.width+ "<" );
        video.style.width = "112px";
        video.style.height = "63px";
        alert ( ">" + video.style.width+ "<" );
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

The page is loaded, and the first alert ( which should have the width of the iframe ) only shows "><", without the width of the video in between.

I am sure that it's not because the video object is null. The following lines resize it as expected. After the resizing, the same alert brings up the correct width.

Is there anything I can do to have the width available straight away?

I am not a big fan of libraries such as jQuery, but happy to consider in case one of them gives a straight forward solution which doesn't make it more complicated than just parsing the string inside the  tag. Just in case the page needs some maintenance in the future...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to set the style attribute to match your width and height attributes:

```
<iframe style="width:420;height:315" width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a34QTcpnKww"     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

Because in your function, you are working with the style attribute.

Comment: 1. This is hacky. 2. The `iframe` code comes from Youtube/Vimeo/etc so he cannot change it I guess.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! As obvious as it was, I hadn't noticed that there was no "style" attribute. And didn't know that you can also call the object.width instead of object.style.width. I tried it and it works :) I will stick to this, as some users with no knowledge of html at all could be adding the videos, and asking them to edit the embed code would be asking a bit too much

Comment: @Dan Not on all HTML objects.

Answer (score 1):

### DOM: element.offset*

[offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight) should help, [supported even in IE6 and all modern browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t34).

```
alert ( ">" + video.offsetWidth +  "<" );
```

Please take a look [the jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KN2zH/).

### jQuery width()/height()

If you feel ready to use **jQuery**, check out [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/). I am not a "fan" of jQuery either, but if you're tired of working around browser inconsistencies, need advanced event handling support (instead of your current inline event handlers) and great DOM helpers, it is an amazing tool to have.

### Attributes

Another way would be to simply retrieve the HTML attribute's content (being `width="420"`). You can do that using `.getAttribute(width)` or `.width` (which accesses the DOM property).

```
 alert ( ">" + video.width +  "<" );
 alert ( ">" + video.getAttribute(width) +  "<" );
```